# onFullSync action, show updated info - DHTMLX Grid + RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dhtmlx

I have a Ruby on Rails project where I use a DHTMLX Grid.

Is there a way of showing, using the event handler "onFullSync" provided by the grid API, to show updated data?

Let me explain a little better... I know I can do something like:

```
dp.attachEvent("onFullSync", function(){
       alert("update complete");
  })
```

But what I want is something more complex. I want to, after each completed update, alter a div adding the information like this:

- Field 2 was updated to XYZ and field 3 was updated to XER on line X
- Field 1 was updated to 123 and field 3 was updated to XSD on line Y

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I end up doing was:

After creating the grid I created an array:

```
var samples = [];
```

Then, as per @Aquatic suggestion, I added to "onEditCell" event the following line:

```
samples[samples.length] = grid.cells(rId, 5).getValue();
```

This allowed me to add to the array the value present on column 5 of the row changed. Then, on "onFullSync" event I hide or show the div created on the view with the messages (I distinguish if it's on row or more changed on the grid).

```
//Deals with messages after update
dp.attachEvent("onFullSync", function(){
  unique_samples = uniq_fast(samples.sort());
    if (unique_samples.length == 1){
      $('#updated-samples').text("");
      $(".messages").show();
      $('#updated-samples').text("A seguinte amostra foi actualizada: " + unique_samples[0]);
      //to clear the array
      samples = [];
    } else if (unique_samples.length > 1){
        $('#updated-samples').text("");
        $(".messages").show();
        $('#updated-samples').text("As seguintes amostras foram actualizadas: " + unique_samples.sort().join(", "));
        //to clear the array
      samples = [];
       } else {
          $('#updated-samples').text("");
          $(".messages").hide();   
         //to clear the array
      samples = [];          
          } 
  })
```

The problem with using "onEditCell" is that everytime a field is changed on that row I get a repeated value on my "samples" array, I I had to remove duplicate from that array. For that I used one of the suggestions at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

```
  // remove duplicates in array
  function uniq_fast(a) {
      var seen = {};
      var out = [];
      var len = a.length;
      var j = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           var item = a[i];
           if(seen[item] !== 1) {
                 seen[item] = 1;
                 out[j++] = item;
           }
      }
      return out;
  }
```

Then I have on the beginning of the view, to show the messages:

```
<div class="alert alert-success messages" id="updated-samples">
```

And that's it. I could be not the most efficient way but it works for what I wanted. I will leave the question open a few more days to see if any other option appears.

Answer (score 2):

There is a onAfterUpdate event that can be used similar to onFullSync
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dataprocessor_onafterupdate_event.html

It will fire after each data saving operation ( if you are saving 5 rows - it will fire 5 times )
Still, info about updated columns will not be available here.

Also, you can try onEditCell event of grid. It fires after changing data in db, but before real saving in database. Here you can get all necessary info - row, column, old value and new value.

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__link__dhtmlxtreegrid_oneditcell_event.html